# Design with MicroBlaze has more instantiated block-RAMs than device capacity. Consider targetting to a different part

Tags: verilog, vivado

I have a design which is using the Xilinx part: XC7A100T (FGG484ABX21), the environment: WIN10 19043.1348, VIVADO 2018.3. According to the datasheet: https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/documentation/selection-guides/cost-optimized-product-selection-guide.pdf#A7, XC7A100T should have ***4,860 Kb*** (4860*1000/8/1024=***593 KiB***) BRAM, and I am using only ***512 KiB*** of them.

The Memory Address Assignment is as follows:
[image]

VIVADO throws me the error when I try to do the synthesis:
[image]

What could be wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Could be that some part of your logic is mapped to a BRAM which you otherwise don't intend to. Check the logs to figure out what all logic is being mapped to a BRAM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

:) Thanks man @Pradyuman Bissa. Problem resolved. The GPIB FIFO uses nearly 50% of the BRAMs.